# Как изменить значение id?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Допустим есть код:

```
bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "text")
```

Даный код отправит текст пользователю, который напишет боту. Как сделать чтобы значение from_user было то, которое ты ему укажешь.

Comment: Зачем вы лезете в телеботы и аиограмы, если не знаете основ?

Answer (score 0):

```
user_id = "тут айди"

bot.send_message(user_id, "текст сообщения")
```

И дальше меняешь значение переменной user_id